# foreach in Java: is having the statement which calculates the iterable object worse than having a variable in the loop?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

Working at object mapping with Java and JDBC for SQL Server I wondered myself if I would create a variable to save the value that returns a select sentence or if I could put the sentence in the foreach loop.

I have post the complete function but the question is only about the foreach loop. Both options works good for me, but I wanted to know if there is any difference about efficiency or if exists any case where the first one could fail.

```
public static List<User> UserList()
{
    BD miBD = new BD(BD_SERVER,BD_NAME);
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>(); 

    for(Object[] tuple: miBD.Select("SELECT name,password FROM tUser;"))
    {
        String id = (String)tuple[0];
        String p = (String)tuple[1];
        User u = new User(id,p);
        list.add(u);
    }

    return list;
}
```

*or*

```
    List<Object[]> tupleList = miBD.Select("SELECT name,password FROM tUser;") 
    for(Object[] tuple: tupleList)
    {
        String id = (String)tuple[0];
        String p = (String)tuple[1];
        User u = new User(id,p);
        list.add(u);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

**Which is more advisable to use?**

Comment: Use the one you find the most readable. They do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance they are exactly the same.

The first variant is one line shorter so go with that.